# Char Array Declaration Crashes Program

Tags: c, arrays, char

So, I'm getting a really weird error in my program, and I've narrowed it down to something to do with `getline()` and declaring an array of size greater than 8. However, I'm super confused as to why it's doing that, so any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void populateConfig();

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
    // when thing is size 8 it works fine
    char thing[9];
    populateConfig();

    return 0;
}

void populateConfig(){
    FILE *fp;
    char string1[1000], string2[1000];
    char *line;
    int len = 0;

    fp = fopen("ws.conf", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", string1) != -1){
        // Commenting out if statement prevents crash
        if(string1[0] == '#'){
            getline(&line, &len, fp);
            continue;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

So I'm just reading in a config file, and as shown, when I change the size of `thing` to 8 or less, it works, and when I comment out the `if` statement in `populateConfig()` it also works. Is this something to do with the stack or memory? Should I do something differently?

Comment: Sounds like the `char thing[]` array is acting like a shim under one of the legs of a 4 legged stool.  Get rid of it, and debug the `populateConfig()` function.

Comment: `getline(&line, &len, fp);` is a bug because `line` is uninitialized, but the `getline` function reads its value. Please consult the documentation of `getline`.

Comment: Also, the fscanf return check should be `== 1`, not `!= -1`

Comment: `char *line;
    int len = 0;` --> `char *line = NULL; size_t len = 0;`

Comment: `populateConfig()` worked exactly how I wanted it to. The problem had to do with the seg fault when declaring the char array `thing`. Was fixed by assigning NULL to `line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `char *line` to NULL first. Then before returning, free it.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

Comment: This works! I see that it is good to initialize to NULL, and of course free up memory when done with it, but is there some good explanation of why it causes memory in another function to crash, or do I just make the C gods made and they spite me?

Comment: LOL. Yeah the C gods spite everyone, so @mana624 don't take it personally. If I had a dollar every time I got a seg fault, I'd be a rich man. According to the documentation, the `getline` function will use whatever pointer you give it as the buffer, realloc if necessary, and return as the new pointer. Unless you pass NULL. If you pass NULL it will allocate a buffer for you and return that pointer. Since your pointer was uninitialized, it didn't point to anything valid, and `getline` was crashing or causing undefined behavior and something else unrelated was crashing.